# how to replace a specific string using regular expressions in js?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a block of html string in following format:

`<td>3</td><td>2</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</td><td>hallo</td>`

i need to remove first  block using regular expressions. contents of the  tag might be any string.

thanks.

Comment: Can there be a nested tag?

Comment: It would be better avoiding the use of regex to parse/edit HTML, use the DOM instead.

Comment: var strnew=str.toLowerCase(); var delim = strnew.indexOf("</td>"); str=(delim>=0 ? str.substring(delim+5) : str);   is one dirty hack.

Comment: @RohitJain no, Only Text Strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var s = "<td>3</td><td>2</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</td><td>hallo</td>";

s.replace(/^<td>.+?<\/td>/, "")

// returns "<td>2</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>bar</td><td>hallo</td>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of jquery. It will make your life very very easy.

Use the following code :

```
  $("#myTable tr td:first-child").remove();
```

**Working Demo :**  http://jsfiddle.net/DLXCA/